# R - Modifying data frame column names from values in another data frame

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data frame called df1 similar to the following:

```
  Year S4 S1 S2 S3
1 2001  2  5  4  4
2 2002  5  2  2  0
3 2003  7  9  3  6
4 2004  9  6  8  7
5 2005  2  2  6  4
6 2006 10  5  7  5
```

and another data frame df2 like this:

```
  ID    Name
1 S1    John
2 S2   Sarah
3 S3    Kate
4 S4 Michael
```

and I want to change the relevant column names (i.e. not the year) of df1 to the corresponding names in df2, so that df 1 would look like this:

```
  Year Michael John Sarah Kate
1 2001       2    5     4    4
2 2002       5    2     2    0
3 2003       7    9     3    6
4 2004       9    6     8    7
5 2005       2    2     6    4
6 2006      10    5     7    5
```

I've tried the following:

```
cols <- names(df1)
cols <- cols[2:length(cols)]
newCols = df2[cols == df2$ID, "Name"]
names(df1) <- c("Year", newCols)
```

But the third line only seems to work if the columns in df1 and rows in df2 are in the same order, which they are not. Is there a simple way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
names(df1)[-1] <-  df2$Name[match(names(df1)[-1], df2$ID)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. It seems because df2$name is of type 'factor', the order isn't maintained and also the columns are assigned the integer values rather than strings. I'm new to R and don't really understand why this is happening, but the column names are assigned 3, 1, 4, 2 rather than Michael, John, Sarah, Kate.

Comment: @RoryDevitt  That is an easy fix.  `as.character(df2$Name[match(names(df1)[-1], as.character(df2$ID))]`